# Extending type class membership to collections

Tags: scala, typeclass

This is my first question, so I hope I am doing everything correctly.

My situation is this: I want to use a typeclass to express that certain types are closed under a function. Concretely, the type class is called `Substitutable`. The intention is that if `T` is an instance of `Substitutable`, then you can apply a substitution to it and get a `T` in return. This is realized by a method `applySubstitution` that each instance of `Substitutable` must implement.

Collections inherit this closure property; if I apply a substitution element-wise to a list of `T`s, where `T` is an instance of `Substitutable`, then the result will again be a list of `T`s, so `List[T]` is itself an instance of `Substitutable`.

In short, I want to make `List[T]` an instance of `Substitutable` if `T` is an instance. I cannot see how to express this. The way I see it, I would need to write something like

```
implicit objectSubstitutableList[T: Substitutable] extends Substitutable[List[T]],
```

but this is not possible because I can't give a type parameter to the implicit object.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an implicit def, since the typeclass for List[T] needs an implicit argument (the typeclass instance for T).

```
trait Substitutable[T] {
  def applySubstitution(value: T, f: String => String): T 
}

object Substitutable {
  implicit def listIsSubstitutable[T: Substitutable]: Substitutable[List[T]] =
    new Substitutable[List[T]] {
      def applySubstitution(value: List[T], f: String => String): List[T] =
        value.map(x => implicitly[Substitutable[T]].applySubstitution(x, f))
    }
}
```

Define a typeclass instance for String

```
implicit val stringIsSubstitutable: Substitutable[String] =
  new Substitutable[String] {
    def applySubstitution(value: String, f: String => String) = f(value)
  }
```

Typeclass instance for List[String] is automatically generated

```
scala> implicitly[Substitutable[List[String]]]
res3: Substitutable[List[String]] = Substitutable$$anon$2@30376991
```

This does not work, because there is no Substitutable[Int] in the implicit scope.

```
scala> implicitly[Substitutable[List[Int]]]
<console>:14: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: Substitutable[List[Int]]
```